# Swipe to refresh leaderboard

Tags: lists, scrolling, touch-screen, swipe

Our mobile game has a leaderboard widget with names and scores:

[image: leaderboard]

This is a scrollable list with 50 to 100 elements in it, sorted by score. One entry is for the current user, others are for his opponents. Scores may change in the real time - every user has a chance to play the game as much as they like, and their best score is recorded.

We do not want to implement live updates in this widget, as this does not make much sense for our application (and this data does not change that often, maybe one change every 10 minutes).

Is swipe to refresh a good solution here? I have concerns about it, because it requires the user to scroll all the way to the top and not really intuitive in my opinion.

Comment: You can provide a refresh button in the app header which will stick to the top and in doing so the user will not have to scroll up in order to refresh.

Comment: For a mobile game whose results change that infrequently, I'm not sure there's a need for any refresh mechanism at all; why would a user stay on the leaderboard view for ten minutes?  Just show the current results whenever the leaderboard is opened.

Answer (score 3):

A swipe down, aka pull to refresh would be an option if you did not want to use on-screen controls.

Could add a small timestamp at the top, and the app auto updates.